# YII2 user management

Tags: php, yii2

don't know why it happens, here is the sample of the code

```
$uid = Yii::$app->user->identity->ID;

        if($id != null){
            $model = self::findOne($id);
        }
        else{
            $model = self::find()->select('ID, connection_uri, version, username, password')->where('
            enabled = :en AND user_id = :userid    
            ' ,[':en' => 1, ':userid' => $uid])->one();
        }
```

When this line is being processed `$uid = Yii::$app->user->identity->ID;`
the whole server is getting very slower and I cannot do any other thing only to wait while the function is being finished. When I delete that line and for example type this : `$uid = 1;` then everything is ok. Do you have any ideas why it might happen?

Comment: enable yii2 debug panel and check profiler and logs page maybe you can find why it is so slow. maybe if not why but at least what exactly is slowing your app down.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
 $uid = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
```

Comment: nope, this is correct Yii::$app->user->identity->ID; it gives me ID because this attr is set in user object model

Comment: no good, `id` is an user identity  variable.  this is the problem.....! http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

Comment: $uid = Yii::$app->user->getId();

Comment: think it's yii2 bug, just installed new yii2 app, and put this code to test 
$id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
        {
            echo $id;
            sleep(1);
        }

so, the same problem